# Discord.JS:TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is the code.

```
case 'updatesrole' :
    msg.react("✔️")
    msg.reply("✔️ Added updates role!, to remove, do !removeupdatesrole")
    let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Updates");

    var member1 = msg.author
    member1.roles.add(role)

case 'removeupdatesrole' :
    member1.roles.remove(role)
    }
})
```

I get this error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: Was it referencing the `roles` property from the `removeupdatesrole` case, or the `updatesrole`

Comment: removeupdatesrole. @Lioness100

Answer (score 0):

## Case statements are separate blocks of code

If I'm reading the code correctly (the formatting is a little weird) you have a switch statement and define a variable in one of the cases. If different case is triggered (in this case (haha), "removeupdatesrole") then that variable is never created and the error is thrown. In order to use the variable you either need to create it within the case like so:

```
case 'removeupdatesrole' :
  var member1 = msg.member
  member1.roles.remove(role)
}
```

Or create it before the entire switch statement if multiple cases use it.

Alternatively, you could simplify your code to this:

```
case 'removeupdatesrole' :
  msg.member.roles.remove(role)
}
```

and never have to deal with the variable at all.

P.S: After you fix this, you'll have to do the same with the role variable. Declare it in the 'removeupdatesrole' case statement too.

**Edit:** As Lioness100 points out in the comments, msg.member should be used instead of msg.author in order to get the user in the context of the Guild instead of Discord at large. I have updated the code snippets accordingly.

Comment: **Remember**, `msg.author` returns a user object, when you need a `GuildMember` object. Make sure to use `msg.member` instead.

Comment: Im getting the error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'role' before initialization now.

Comment: @moiboi that's because you haven't declared the role variable in the second case statement, just like you hadn't declared the member1 variable (hence my P.S.). You have to create the role variable within the second case statement before you can use it.